# Time complexity of a loop with few operations

Tags: c++

It is known that a while-loop(Ex: `while(n--)`) or a for-loop(Ex: `for(i=0; i<n; i++)`)'s time of execution depends on the variable n, i.e. `O(n)`. Also, on an online judge, 10^7 operations ≈ 1s.
But I tried executing a while-loop and a for-loop for `n > 10^9` with few operations and it seems to run easily under 1 sec. I am curious why this is happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long 
int main(){
    ll t = 1e18;
    ll cnt = 0;
    while(t--){
        cnt++;
    }
    cout << cnt << '\n';
    cerr << "Time elapsed: " << 1.0 * clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " s.\n";
}

Output: 1000000000000000000
Time elapsed: 0.003174 s.
```

Comment: The time complexity does not change and remains O(n). But the CPU may cache the instructions and so will execute them "bloody fast". Or the compiler has optimized the entire loop away and just assigned `cnt= 1e18;`

Comment: Condition `10^7 operations ≈ 1s` is never static and differs on different platforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you write is not instructions for your cpu, but instructions for your compiler to generate instructions for your cpu. In this specific case it is rather simple to see that this

```
long long  t = 1e18;
long long cnt = 0;
while(t--){
    cnt++;
}
cout << cnt << '\n';
```

can be replaced by

```
long long cnt = 1e18;
cout << cnt << '\n';
```

without altering the observable behavior of the program.

Comment: What other operations are not dependent on the loop?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar sorry, i dont understand your question. In your code nothing depends on the loop because all it does is `cnt = 1e18;` and `t = 0;` but you are not using `t` after the loop so it doesnt matter whether the loops decrements it or not

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR : The compiler simply discarded your loop , cleared `t` and stuck 1e18 into `cnt`. If you want to know how I came to this conclusion,read on:

On my computer and `g++ -O1/-O0` the program took litraly forever to run but using `-O2` it finished instantly (the same as the asker's situation), so I will use the `-S -O2` assembly code:

```
leaq    _ZSt4cout(%rip), %rdi
    movabsq $1000000000000000000, %rsi
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIxEERSoT_@PLT
    leaq    7(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    $1, %edx
    movb    $10, 7(%rsp)
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l@PLT
```

Clearly the compiler just stuck 1e18 into `cnt` (`movabsq XXX %rsi`), set `t` to 0 (using the magic of `xorl %eax %eax` to clear `%eax`) then skipped the loop (there was no `jmp` or `je` or similar commands,and proceeded to `cout` (via `call _XXX_insert_XXX` and later `_ostream_insertXXX`)

Answer (score -2):

The time complexity for a simple loop (doesn't really matter which type) is O(n), that's clear.

---

But you should know that CPU's store some information in its fast access cache that is frequently used. However, the **compiler** optimizes the code by identifying which instructions (code) can be altered to produce lesser instructions while retaining the logic. While compiler optimization is a huge topic, loops are a prime target since they repeat the same set of instructions over and over.

---

And let's just consider the fact that a modern CPU executing a highly optimized set of compiled instructions at ~3 billion ops/sec will blaze through the instructions in microseconds.

Comment: I am not sure  it is the compiler that does this task of optimization by identifying which instructions (code) needs caching. The compiler's instructions cannot dictate the CPU which instructions to cache. The CPU does that itself.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie , seems you are right. The CPU has it's own hardware and instructions to manage caching. I only remembered the use of TLB and and cache writing policies after reading your comment. CPU handles the cache but code optimization is done mostly by the compiler.